# How to pull code from another domain

Tags: php, jquery, include, cross-domain

if I had several websites and I would want to read "file.html" in every website, how should I do that? The file.html would be just like this:

```
<h1>Hot news</h1>
<p>article</p>
```

I know I can use php include or require,

```
<? include 'file.html'; ?>
```

or jQuery, but only within a domain.

```
.load("file.html");
```

How should I do that cross-domain?

PS: And yes, I know that's insecure

Comment: can't do it cross-domain unless the remote server supports JSONP requests, e.g. you can't steal another site's html with javascript unless that site cooperates with you. You could try doing something with iframes, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP for it:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://....'); ?>
```

The reason why `include` doesn't work is that url includes are disabled by default since they are horribly insecure - the included document is handled as PHP. However, with `file_get_contents` no PHP code can be injected and thus it's pretty safe (except client-side things such as XSS if the remote site sends you bad JavaScript code).